# An example for N50? Why do we need it?

Tags: bioinformatics

I'm trying to understand N50 on the wikipedia. But I was unable to get a sense of the definition:

> Given a set of contigs, each with its own length, the N50 length is
>   defined as the length for which the collection of all contigs of that
>   length or longer contains at least half of the sum of the lengths of
>   all contigs, and for which the collection of all contigs of that
>   length or shorter also contains at least half of the sum of the
>   lengths of all contigs.

Is there a simple example that illustrates this definition? Furthermore, why do we need this statistic? What does it really tell me? Do we want a higher or less value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contig or scaffold N50 is a weighted median statistic such that 50% of the entire assembly is contained in contigs or scaffolds equal to or larger than this value.

Mathematically:

> Given a set of sequences of varying lengths, the N50 length is defined
>   as the length N for which 50% of all bases in the sequences are in a
>   sequence of length L < N. This can be found mathematically as follows:
>   Take a list L of positive integers. Create another list L' , which is
>   identical to L, except that every element n in L has been replaced
>   with n copies of itself. Then the median of L' is the N50 of L. For
>   example: If L = {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 8, 8}, then L' consists of six 2's,
>   six 3's, four 4's, and sixteen 8's; the N50 of L is the median of L' ,
>   which is 6.

In simple words:

> scaffold N50 is the median contig size of your genomic assembly. It's
>   a metric that you can use to evaluate the quality of your assembly,
>   since an overly small N50 suggests that you were unable to generate
>   many contigs of biologically meaningful size (i.e. you probably have a
>   lot of bogus little contigs in your assembly). You can increase your
>   N50 by eliminating sequences which are bound to cause you problems,
>   e.g. short repetitive stretches.
>
> note that this metric only applies when doing de novo assembly. If you
>   are aligning to a reference (i.e. for variant discovery applications)
>   this metric doesn't apply

For a sample workout on an arbitrary small dataset:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/calculating-an-n50-from-velvet-output/

This answer was compiled from multiple sources:

http://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_N50_Scaffold_in_Genome_sequencing_Technique
http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2332
https://www.broad.harvard.edu/crd/wiki/index.php/N50